# how to download open source code of spring framework or it modules for checking the internal working

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

i want to know spring open source jar so that i can check the internal working of spring libraries.how to work like BeanFactory,ApplicationContext etc.

please tell me the links to download these things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Repository like Github has huge source of open-source codebase ,
>   please investigate your query on Github.

Source code and reference for Application Context on Github : [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext.java)